# How to filter out identical rows on unknown table with dynamic columns in KQL?

Tags: kql

I need to filter out identical row in an **unknown** input table in KQL.

At first, I used "distinct *", this worked great on tables which don't have columns of type "dynamic" but fails when it does.
I need to support dynamic columns as well.

I'm currently trying out the following solution. example:

```
datatable(DepId:string, d:dynamic)[
"123456789", dynamic({'Person': { 'Name' : 'DuDu', 'SuperPower' : 'Kql', 'Company' : { 'Name' : 'Microsoft' }}}),
"123456789", dynamic({'Person': { 'Name' : 'DuDu', 'SuperPower' : 'Kql', 'Company' : { 'Name' : 'Microsoft' }}}),
"123456789", dynamic({'Person': { 'Name' : 'Anat', 'SuperPower' : 'Kql', 'Company' : { 'Name' : 'Microsoft' }}})]
| summarize take_any(*) by all=tostring(pack_all())
| project-away all
```

This seems to get the correct result.
Is there a better solution?
This is done on a small time window, but can it be a performance risk?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for getting a canonical string representation of a `dynamic` value, which you can use for de-duplication, you can use the [`dynamic_to_json` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dynamic-to-json-function).

Is it efficient to perform this kind of de-duplication at query time? No. You'd be better off figuring out the source of the duplicates and preventing them from being ingested in the first place.

- If you can't, you can look at how to [Handle duplicate data in Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/dealing-with-duplicates).